# How many ways are there to fill a 3 × 3 grid with 0s and 1s?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, isometry

Extra conditions that put a formal solution out of my reach: the centre cell must contain a $0$, and two grids are equal if they have a symmetry, e.g.
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1\end{array} \right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0\end{array} \right)
$$
For context, this question is part of an investigation into the number of possible checkmate patterns in chess.

Comment: When you say symmetry, it means "up to a rotation", right ? Do you include "true" symmetries (mirror symmetries wrt an axis, vertical, horizontal, at 45°) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The example matrices imply that reflections and rotations are considered equivalent.

Comment: For this one-time calculation, I wouldn't bother trying to analyze it by hand. Just write a program. The time to write the program shouldn't be that much greater than the time for a by-hand analysis. Also, the code could be reused in the future for similar problems.

Comment: @quasi I fully agree with you.

Comment: @quasi Don't bother with a computer. Burnside's lemma works here.

Comment: @Ah, Ok -- nice.

Comment: Related (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1831582) and 
(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570003/how-many-unique-patterns-exist-for-a-nxn-grid/587729#587729)

Comment: If the zeros and ones are Fermions rather than Bosons, you have more possiblities.  And yes, you dopes, that's a joke.

Comment: Please accept my answer since it is the correct one.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma). The number of symmetries of the matrix is eight:

- the identity, leaving $2^8$ admissible matrices unchanged (the centre cell being fixed)
- two 90° rotations leaving $2^2$ matrices unchanged each
- a 180° rotation leaving $2^4$ matrices unchanged
- four reflections leaving $2^5$ matrices unchanged each

So the number of possible matrices up to symmetry is
$$\frac{2^8+2\cdot2^2+2^4+4\cdot2^5}8=32+1+2+16=51$$

Comment: [+1] Burnside's lemma... what a tool...

Comment: I notice (wiki page) that  "..there are 57 rotationally distinct colourings of the faces of a cube in three colours."    Same as the number of Heinz ketchup types.  Coincidence? Alien influence?